# Sitecore Spatial search results are inconsistant

Tags: search, sitecore, spatial, sitecore8

I am having an issue where our spatial results are coming back incomplete immediately after we rebuild our index.  If I then recycle the app pool (or do an iis reset for that matter) it will then return the full expected list of results.  This is of obvious concerns, since we do not want to have to recycle the app pool every time the index may get rebuilt.

Comment: What index strategy are you using?

Comment: The problem is not so much the strategy, but a .net or Sitecore caching issue.  If I rebuild my index (using straight Lucene with very little modifications from a base example index file), I will get, say 20 results within a given radius.  If I then recycle the app pool, I then get the total number of expected results, around 58.  It is consistent that after I rebuild the index the results are severely truncated, but the number returned varies every time I rebuild the index

Answer (score 0):

After much testing we found that there were a few issues in our configuration of the indexes and the code of the computed fields:

1. Our default index configuration was incorrect for the spatial search.
2. Our computed fields had a boost set.  This seemed to interfere with the results
3. we were encoding the lat and long on the computed fields.  This has been removed.
4. set the ContentSearch.ParallelIndexing.Enabled setting to false.  I still have not found why this was causing issues but once it was turned off, the newly rebuilt index was working as expected.

For item one we found the solution on the [sitecore community site](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/7/t/4447)

Comment: If this is still a problem, The module have been updated on github and all the issues have been fixed https://github.com/aokour/Sitecore.ContentSearch.Spatial